# Using sed to delete everything between two words?

Tags: sed

[This](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51) doesn't seem to work

```
The next example would delete everything between "ONE" and "TWO:" 

#!/bin/sh
sed '
/ONE/ {
# append a line
    N
# search for TWO on the second line 
    /\n.*TWO/ {
# found it - now edit making one line
        s/ONE.*\n.*TWO/ONE TWO/
    }
}' file
```

i was expecting to delete everything between ONE and TWO.i tried with file
where file contains.

```
[user5@mailserver ~]$ cat file
ONE
hello
TWO
```

but the output come like

```
[user5@mailserver ~]$ ./test
ONE
hello
TWO
```

I was expecting `ONE TWO`
I am trying to make it correct but not able to do.

Comment: I'd simply use a small PCRE, with by replacing `s/ONE.*TWO/ONE\nTWO/n` something like this. make sure your Regexp matches *around* newlines! Here's an answer that'll probably solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624283/how-to-tell-sed-dot-match-new-line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do the job

```
sed '/^ONE/,/TWO/{/^ONE/!{/TWO/!d}}' file
```

`/^ONE/,/TWO/` Look at the first line starting with `ONE` up to `TWO`

`{/^ONE/!` do the following if my line does not start with `ONE`

`{/TWO/!d}}` do the following if my line does not start with `TWO` and `delete`

To summerize the above:

Find everything that starts with `ONE` up to `TWO`. Another check is ran which means, find everything that don't match 'ONE`and`TWO` and delete the rest.

Answer (score 2):

I would use

```
sed 'N;N;s/ONE.*\n.*TWO/ONE TWO/' file
```

Note the two `N` operations to join three lines together to allow the `s` opertation to work.

(this also keeps close to your original example).